# moving a point in 3d space

Tags: c++, math, opengl, coordinates

I have a point at 0,0,0
I rotate the point 30 deg around the Y axis, then 30 deg around the X axis.
I then want to move the point 10 units forward.

I know how to work out the new X and Y position

```
MovementX = cos(angle) * MoveDistance;
MovementY = sin(angle) * MoveDistance;
```

But then I realised that these values will change because of Z, won't they?

How do I work out Z and have I worked out X and Y correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: Use rotation matrices. :) They take a considerable investment of effort to learn but once you know how to use them everything becomes much less work.

Comment: Ok I guess the equivalent in OpenGL would be...

glRotatef( 30.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );

glRotatef( 30.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );

glTranslate( 0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f );

But I want to do it manually so that I know the world coordinates of the point (so that I can compare it to other coordinates)

Comment: I don't know too much about OpenGL but if your point is starting at (0,0,0) then drhirsch is correct and your point won't be moving anywhere through rotations. So the only function that would do anything is the glTranslate. Therefore your new position would be (0,0,10). However I feel like that might not be what you were going for. Are you sure your point doesn't have a direction vector associated with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should multiply point coordinates to full rotation matrix, which is `matRotationTotal = matRotationX * matRotationY * matRotationZ`. Check [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/3d/rotationMatrices.html) article for details.